# Export using Bcp

Tags: sql-server

I am exporting data using bcp and using union all to combine the column data with column header,I have used orderby variable and set it to 0 for the header and then to 1 for the column data inorder to have the header at the top in the excel file but it seems to place the header in between the data on some occasions when the no. of rows is more than 17,000

Comment: You are going to have to show us the code.

Comment: Please add more details to this question. The question may be clear to you , but  as it stands it's very vague to us as we don't know the system you are working with. It could use some sample data and desired output as a minimum along with what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use following format for your query:

```
Select * 
From (Select 0 as [Type], 'Header1' as Col1, 'Header2' as Col2 ,...
      UNION 
      Select 1 as [Type], Col1, Col2, ...
      From YourTable
     )z
Order by Z.[Type]
```